# How can I check how many followers someone has on Instagram with Python?

Tags: python, api, instagram

So I want to be able to input a username into my Python program and then it checks how many followers that account has (if it's not private) and displays the number. I'm sure it has something to do with APIs.

Comment: Check this out? https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram

Answer (score 2):

You can use this API endpoint:

```
https://instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1
```

It returns a JSON representation of the account information.

Example: https://instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1

Answer (score 1):

first idea that came to my mind is to scrape it with beautifulsoup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up.